# How to make different classes based on different input parameters in python

Tags: python, class

I want to create instances of a class returning nx.graph based on different parameters. My approach is to use sort of factory pattern for this.

```
class Erdos_Renyi(object):
      
    def __init__(n, p):
        self.n = n
        self.p = n

    def simulate_graph(self):
        return nx.erdos_renyi_graph(self.n, self.p)


class Watts_Strogatz(object):
    
    def __init__(n, k, p):
        self.n = n
        self.p = n
        self.k = k

    def simulate_graph(self):
        return nx.watts_strogatz_graph(self.n, self.k, self.p)


class Barabasi_Albert(object):
    
    def __init__(n, m):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m

    def simulate_graph(self):
        return nx.barabasi_albert_graph(self.n, self.m)


class Network_Simulation_Class:

    def __init__(self, n, **kargs):
        self.n = n
        if k in kargs:
            self.g = Watts_Strogatz(p, k)
        elif m in kargs:
            self.g = Barabasi_Albert(self.n, m)
        else:
            self.g = Erdos_Renyi(self.n, p)
```

Something like this. I hope you understand what i'm about to do.
For example if i call `Network_Simulation_Class(1000, k=3, p=0.1)`
Because i input k. So it will create an instance Watts_Strogatz
It's not working now. How to make changes

Comment: You want `"k"`, not `k`

Comment: FYI you don't need to specifically list `object` as a parent class in Python 3.x. It's the default.

Comment: Several of your `__init__()` methods are missing the `self` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need so many classes. Just a single `NetworkSimulation` class that does what you want based on the arguments it receives:

```
class NetworkSimulation:
    def __init__(self, n, **kargs):
        self.n = n
        if "k" in kargs:
            self.k = kargs["k"]
            self.p = kargs["p"]
            self.g_args = (self.n, self.k, self.p)
            self.g_type = nx.watts_strogatz_graph
        elif "m" in kargs:
            self.m = kargs["m"]
            self.g_args = (self.n, self.m)
            self.g_type = nx.barabasi_albert_graph
        elif "p" in kargs:
            self.p = kargs["p"]
            self.g_args = (self.n, self.p)
            self.g_type = nx.erdos_renyi_graph
        else:
            recd_args = ", ".join(kargs.keys())
            raise TypeError("NetworkSimulation expected arguments (n, k, p), (n, m), or (n, p). Received (n, {recd_args})")

    def simulate_graph(self):
        return self.g_type(*self.g_args)
```

Also note that `kargs` is a *dictionary* where the keys are strings containing the argument names, so you need to do `"m" in kargs` to check if that argument was passed

Comment: Thank you so much! My original plan was to implement a factory pattern. But this will do

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the keyword arguments as ordinary variables, you need to use `kargs['name']`.

When testing whether the argument exists, use a string in the `in` test.

Also, the convention is to use the name `kwargs` for keyword arguments.

```
class Network_Simulation_Class:

    def __init__(self, n, **kwargs):
        self.n = n
        if 'k' in kargs:
            self.g = Watts_Strogatz(n, kwargs['p'], kwargs['k'])
        elif 'm' in kargs:
            self.g = Barabasi_Albert(n, kwargs['m'])
        else:
            self.g = Erdos_Renyi(n, kwargs['p'])
```